# Add column family to the existing hbase table from spark scala shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I have a table(test) in hbase with 2 column families(cf1,cf2) , now I want to add a column family to the existing table in hbase from spark shell. I tried using the below statements but it says the table already exists

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin,HTable,Put,Get}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, HTableDescriptor}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable


val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
conf.set("hbase.rootdir","hdfs://")
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","")
conf.setInt("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", )

val tableName = "test"
val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("cf3"))
admin.createTable(tableDesc)
```

Is there a way to add a column family(cf3) to existing test table in hbase from spark shell using scala?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the table first. Then add columnFamily and enable it back.

```
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
conf.set("hbase.rootdir","hdfs://")
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","")
conf.setInt("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", )

val tableName = "test"
val table = TableName.valueOf(tableName)
admin.disableTable(table) 
admin.addColumn(table,new HColumnDescriptor("cf3"))
admin.enableTable(tableDesc)
```

In Java, it will equivalent to this :

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
Admin admin = new Admin(conf);
TableName table = TableName.valueOf("myTable");

admin.disableTable(table);

HColumnDescriptor cf1 = ...;
admin.addColumn(table, cf1);      // adding new ColumnFamily
HColumnDescriptor cf2 = ...;
admin.modifyColumn(table, cf2);    // modifying existing ColumnFamily

admin.enableTable(table);
```